# Binary classification of images in Keras

Tags: neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, keras

I am trying to classify images (29 x 29) using only 1 channel in Keras. If the middle pixel is in a certain range, then the output is 1, if not then it is 0.

For the training set I have 10000 images with output 1 and 30000 images with output 0 and I am using the following architecture:

```py
model = Sequential()

# kernel = (4, 4); 6 outputmaps  26x26 
model.add(Convolution2D(6, 4, 4, input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_columns)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# 6 outputmaps of 13x13
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# 12 outputmaps of 10x10 ; kernel = (4, 4)
model.add(Convolution2D(12, 4, 4))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# 12 outputmaps of 5x5
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# 24 outputmaps of 4x4 ; kernel = (2, 2)
model.add(Convolution2D(24, 2, 2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

For compilation, I am using the binary_crossentropy loss

```py
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', class_mode='binary')
```

The accuracy fluctuates, but it reaches a final value of 0.75 after each epoch. 
Is there anything I am missing? Is there anything I should change or add in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to interpret your approach, you want your CNN to only look at 1 of 29*29 pixels. I'm not an expert but this does not sound like a good problem for a CNN. However, usually if your network achieves bad results on the training data, your network is too small. So you could try to make it bigger. Another things you can think about: What do your settings (kernel size, layers, pooling) actually achieve? Could your settings be bad for this kind of task? Here is what I would do:

- try this without CNN, i.e. use 1 or 2 fully connected layer and see what happens
- make the resolution 'finer', i.e. use (3,3) filter size
- remove maxpooling (maxpooling throws away information to make features more invariant, I don't see that you would need this)
- add more conv layers
- might not be relevant, but your data set is very small so you don't need the speed benefit of sgd, go for another optimizer instead

How exactly does your training and testing look like? Is this a toy project?